# How to compare vector with a value in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have six node (1-6). I have two matrices, "x" and "distance" given below. The distance matrix represents the distance of all the nodes from node 3.

```
x=[1 2 4 6];
distance=[110 115 0 16 10 2];
```

I want to make an if condition that should take some action if the distance of any of the nodes in matrix x from node 3 is greater than 13. I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
if distance(1,x(1:4))<13
c=222;
end
```

I can do it using for loop, but i need a shorter command. Regards.

Comment: What is your desired output for this case?

Comment: @beaker: thank you but I have already got an answer that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the output of `distance(1,x(1:end)) < 13` is a vector, your code doesn't work, you can do this:

```
if ( sum(distance(x) < 13) > 0 )
   c = 222;
end
```